# DateTime.Kind set to unspecified, not UTC, upon loading from database

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, sql-server-2012

When I create a `Buyin` object the response from the ASP.NET MVC controller, (`return Json(response, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`, looks like this:

```
"Buyin": {
        "Id": 95,
        "PlayerSessionId": 88,
        "PlayerId": 45,
        "PlayerName": "Alan",
        "Amount": 888,
        "BuyinType": "Credits",
        "Description": null,
        "Authorized": true,
        "SignPath": "~/Signs/Buyins\\95.png",
        "Payment": null,
        "CreationDate": "/Date(1477242738042)/"
    },
```

If I convert that on [Epoch Converter](http://www.epochconverter.com/) I get this time: `GMT: Sun, 23 Oct 2016 17:12:18.042 GMT`

Looking in the database the stored datetime seems to be correct:

```
95  NULL    1   1   2016-10-23 17:12:18.043
```

**When the response is sent out the `Kind` is set to `UTC`**.

Now I call a controller to get all my data and all of the dates have several hours added to it:

```
 {
    "Id": 95,
    "PlayerSessionId": 88,
    "PlayerId": 45,
    "PlayerName": "Alan",
    "Amount": 888,
    "BuyinType": "Credits",
    "Description": null,
    "Authorized": true,
    "SignPath": "~/Signs/Buyins\\95.png",
    "Payment": null,
    "CreationDate": "/Date(1477267938043)/"
}
```

`1477267938043` = `GMT: Mon, 24 Oct 2016 00:12:18.043 GMT`

However when I request this object I can see that the actual object has the correct date set:
[image]

But the `Kind` is set to `Unspecified` so I think this is causing the problem.

For the moment I don't have not set any globalization settings.

So basically my question is: When ASP.NET MVC loads the dates from the database is there a way to tell the server to load the dates with `Kind` set to `UTC` as I think that is the problem?

The database is saved and loaded using Entity Framework.

**Update after the accepted answer**

The accepted answer was great however my date values was already stored in the Database as UTC dates so I modified `GetDateTime` to this:

```
public override DateTime GetDateTime(int ordinal)
{
    var date = base.GetDateTime(ordinal);
    var utcDate = DateTime.SpecifyKind(date, DateTimeKind.Utc);
    return utcDate;
    //return base.GetDateTime(ordinal).ToUniversalTime();
}
```

Comment: How data is loaded from the DB? Entity framework?

Comment: Yes sir, I will update my question.

Comment: You can use `ObjectMaterialized` event of `DbContext` to specify date time kind for all dates. Another approach - add read only property (getter only) which will specify date time kind.

Comment: You said the problem comes from this kind property being null, but what exactly makes you think that ? The display ? An exeption in the code ?

Comment: @Antoine It comes from the `Kind` being `Unspecified` as you can see on the screen shots. That is what the problem is I assume.

Comment: 7 hours added exactly... You could always do date = (date - 7h) until you know the real answer to this question. I agree it is weird that the kind property is suddently null...

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Assuming you are using EF6 and you want to set the `Kind` property of any `DateTime` value retrieved from the database to `Utc`.

Similar questions have been asked, and the answers tend to suggest hooking into the [`ObjectContext.ObjectMaterialized`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.objectmaterialized(v=vs.110).aspx) event, but it didn't fire for queries that use projection.

The solution I'm going to propose works for both entity and projection queries, by performing the conversion at the `DbDataReader` level (which is used by this type of queries).

In order to do that, we need a custom `DbDataReader` implementation that intercepts the [`GetDateTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getdatetime(v=vs.110).aspx) method. Unfortunately implementing `DbDataReader` derived class requires a lot of boilerplate code. Luckily I already created a base class form my answer to [Dynamic Translate to avoid C# syntax errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39779270/dynamic-translate-to-avoid-c-sharp-syntax-errors/39798961#39798961) which simply delegates each method to the underlying `DbDataReader` instance, so I'll just take it from there:

```
abstract class DelegatingDbDataReader : DbDataReader
{
    readonly DbDataReader source;
    public DelegatingDbDataReader(DbDataReader source)
    {
        this.source = source;
    }
    public override object this[string name] { get { return source[name]; } }
    public override object this[int ordinal] { get { return source[ordinal]; } }
    public override int Depth { get { return source.Depth; } }
    public override int FieldCount { get { return source.FieldCount; } }
    public override bool HasRows { get { return source.HasRows; } }
    public override bool IsClosed { get { return source.IsClosed; } }
    public override int RecordsAffected { get { return source.RecordsAffected; } }
    public override bool GetBoolean(int ordinal) { return source.GetBoolean(ordinal); }
    public override byte GetByte(int ordinal) { return source.GetByte(ordinal); }
    public override long GetBytes(int ordinal, long dataOffset, byte[] buffer, int bufferOffset, int length) { return source.GetBytes(ordinal, dataOffset, buffer, bufferOffset, length); }
    public override char GetChar(int ordinal) { return source.GetChar(ordinal); }
    public override long GetChars(int ordinal, long dataOffset, char[] buffer, int bufferOffset, int length) { return source.GetChars(ordinal, dataOffset, buffer, bufferOffset, length); }
    public override string GetDataTypeName(int ordinal) { return source.GetDataTypeName(ordinal); }
    public override DateTime GetDateTime(int ordinal) { return source.GetDateTime(ordinal); }
    public override decimal GetDecimal(int ordinal) { return source.GetDecimal(ordinal); }
    public override double GetDouble(int ordinal) { return source.GetDouble(ordinal); }
    public override IEnumerator GetEnumerator() { return source.GetEnumerator(); }
    public override Type GetFieldType(int ordinal) { return source.GetFieldType(ordinal); }
    public override float GetFloat(int ordinal) { return source.GetFloat(ordinal); }
    public override Guid GetGuid(int ordinal) { return source.GetGuid(ordinal); }
    public override short GetInt16(int ordinal) { return source.GetInt16(ordinal); }
    public override int GetInt32(int ordinal) { return source.GetInt32(ordinal); }
    public override long GetInt64(int ordinal) { return source.GetInt64(ordinal); }
    public override string GetName(int ordinal) { return source.GetName(ordinal); }
    public override int GetOrdinal(string name) { return source.GetOrdinal(name); }
    public override string GetString(int ordinal) { return source.GetString(ordinal); }
    public override object GetValue(int ordinal) { return source.GetValue(ordinal); }
    public override int GetValues(object[] values) { return source.GetValues(values); }
    public override bool IsDBNull(int ordinal) { return source.IsDBNull(ordinal); }
    public override bool NextResult() { return source.NextResult(); }
    public override bool Read() { return source.Read(); }
    public override void Close() { source.Close(); }
    public override T GetFieldValue<T>(int ordinal) { return source.GetFieldValue<T>(ordinal); }
    public override Task<T> GetFieldValueAsync<T>(int ordinal, CancellationToken cancellationToken) { return source.GetFieldValueAsync<T>(ordinal, cancellationToken); }
    public override Type GetProviderSpecificFieldType(int ordinal) { return source.GetProviderSpecificFieldType(ordinal); }
    public override object GetProviderSpecificValue(int ordinal) { return source.GetProviderSpecificValue(ordinal); }
    public override int GetProviderSpecificValues(object[] values) { return source.GetProviderSpecificValues(values); }
    public override DataTable GetSchemaTable() { return source.GetSchemaTable(); }
    public override Stream GetStream(int ordinal) { return source.GetStream(ordinal); }
    public override TextReader GetTextReader(int ordinal) { return source.GetTextReader(ordinal); }
    public override Task<bool> IsDBNullAsync(int ordinal, CancellationToken cancellationToken) { return source.IsDBNullAsync(ordinal, cancellationToken); }
    public override Task<bool> ReadAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) { return source.ReadAsync(cancellationToken); }
    public override int VisibleFieldCount { get { return source.VisibleFieldCount; } }
}
```

and build the actual class that we need on top of it:

```
class UtcDateTimeConvertingDbDataReader : DelegatingDbDataReader
{
    public UtcDateTimeConvertingDbDataReader(DbDataReader source) : base(source) { }
    public override DateTime GetDateTime(int ordinal)
    {
        return DateTime.SpecifyKind(base.GetDateTime(ordinal), DateTimeKind.Utc);
    }
}
```

Once we have that, we need to plug it into EF infrastructure using EF [interception](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework6/database-command-interception.aspx).

We'll start by creating a custom `DbCommandInterceptor` derived class:

```
class UtcDateTimeConvertingDbCommandInterceptor : DbCommandInterceptor
{
    public override void ReaderExecuted(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<DbDataReader> interceptionContext)
    {
        base.ReaderExecuted(command, interceptionContext);
        if (!(interceptionContext.Result is UtcDateTimeConvertingDbDataReader)
            && interceptionContext.Result != null
            && interceptionContext.Exception == null)
            interceptionContext.Result = new UtcDateTimeConvertingDbDataReader(interceptionContext.Result);
    }
}
```

register it (for instance from your `DbContext` derived class static constructor):

```
public class YourDbContext : DbContext
{
    static YourDbContext()
    {
        DbInterception.Add(new UtcDateTimeConvertingDbCommandInterceptor());
    }
    // ...
}
```

and we are done.

Now every `DateTime` value coming from the database will have `Kind` property set to `Utc`.

Comment: You have a bug in the Interceptor.  Because you're not evaluating whether .Result is of type UtcDateTimeConvertingDbDataReader, it starts putting one inside the other.  Here's the fix:

`if (!(interceptionContext.Result is UtcDateTimeConvertingDbDataReader) &&...`

Comment: Also, you should probably add these to the implementation I think.  It helps when you implement the IDataRecord and IDbDataReader interfaces on the class.

`public new IDataReader GetData(int i) {
            return _source.GetData(i);
        }

        public new void Dispose() {
            // Can't dispose, creates a circular reference.
            this._source.Dispose();
        }`

Comment: @TruthOf42 Can't say w/o benchmarking tests, but IMO should be negligible. If you have benchmarking tests, you can run them with and w/o the interceptor and compare the results.

Comment: @JeffFischer What is the purpose of shadowing `GetData` and `Dispose`?

Comment: @JeffFischer I'm also curious about the potential bug you mention. How would that scenario occur?

Comment: @Stijn Regarding the bug he mentions, it could happen only if you install the interceptor more than once - which wasn't the idea. There is no need to create `Dispose` or override `Dispose(bool)` because it calls `Close` which is already overridden and delegated to `source`. Also there is no need to shadow `GetData` - you could add `protected override DbDataReader GetDbDataReader(int ordinal) { return source.GetData(ordinal); }` which I've missed (it's not used by EF).

Comment: If you also need persisting Local as UTC and querying with Local, refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/7108862/618660

Comment: I wanted to use this but unfortunately anonymous linq queries return the base.getName as the query alias.

Comment: This solution does not work if you are using [Spatial Data Type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/data-types/spatial). It will result in the following exception: "Spatial readers can only be produced from readers of type SqlDataReader"

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem by adding a "read" conversion to my entity in my DBContext `OnModelCreatingPartial` handler.

Note that the `x => x` as the first param to `HasConversion` is for writing to the DB. Here we are just telling it to essentially do nothing. The second param is the read conversion.

I've given an example for both nullable and non-nullable DateTimes.

```
public class YourDbContext: DbContext 
{
   public override void OnModelCreatingPartial(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
   {
      modelBuilder.Entity<YourEntityWithDateTimeColumn>(entity =>
      {
         entity.Property(e => e.YourDateTimeColumnNullable).HasColumnType("datetime").HasConversion(x => x, y => DateTime.SpecifyKind(y.Value, DateTimeKind.Utc));
         entity.Property(e => e.YourDateTimeColumnNotNullable).HasColumnType("datetime").HasConversion(x => x, y => DateTime.SpecifyKind(y, DateTimeKind.Utc));
      }
   }
}
```

Hope that helps!