# C# Reflection Invoke - Returns Generic Object { Type } - Need Type

Tags: c#, entity-framework, reflection, invoke

I have a stored procedure call interface that I'm using to handle results from stored procedures with entity (using `Translate` method to translate the results of our stored procedure into entities that can be tracked and used in EF as normal)

Here's the basic code...

```
List<object> current = new List<object>();
object item = ((Type)currenttype.Current).GetConstructor(System.Type.EmptyTypes).Invoke(new object[0]);

ObjectContext actualContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext;
string className = "";
EntityContainer container = null;
string setName = "";

className = ((Type)currenttype.Current).ToString();
container = actualContext.MetadataWorkspace.GetEntityContainer(((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.DefaultContainerName, DataSpace.CSpace);
setName = (from meta in container.BaseEntitySets
           where meta.ElementType.FullName == className
           select meta.Name).FirstOrDefault();


var t = typeof(ObjectContext).GetMethod("Translate", new Type[] { typeof(DbDataReader), typeof(string), typeof(MergeOption) }).MakeGenericMethod(item.GetType()).Invoke(actualContext, new object[] { reader, setName, MergeOption.AppendOnly });
```

The issue is that I can't do anything with 't' that I want, it's type is listed as
`object {System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectResult<POCOClass>}`.  I can't call any of the normal methods that I can normally on the ObjectResult type such as `ToArray` or `ToList`.

I need a way to convert it into `System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectResult<POCOClass>`. The difference being that 't' is listed as type object first.

I cannot use any strongly typed casts because the types will change depending on the stored procedure. I've tried using the dynamic keyword instead of var for t and I've also tried using `Convert.ChangeType`. It never changes from the object base type. dynamic t returns this the following error:

> 'System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectResult<POCOClass>' does not contain a definition for 'ToList'

Thought I know for a fact it does...

To clear up confusion, here's a watch screenshot. The first line is what's being returned, I want it to be like the second (see Type column).

**Edit**: might be getting closer... I added this:

```
var listedT = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethod("ToList").MakeGenericMethod(item.GetType()).Invoke(null, new object[] { t });
current.AddRange(listedT); // Error here...
```

listedT becomes a `object {System.Collections.Generic.List<ReportCatalog.Models.Catalog_Reports>}` and I get the error, cannot convert from object to System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<object>.

[image]

Comment: Do you mean to say you are getting type `System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectResult<POCOClass>` but you really want type `POCOClass`?

Comment: No, I'm getting object {System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectResult<POCOClass>} and I want just System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectResult<POCOClass>...

Comment: What does `object { ... }` mean? Is it a boxed value? If this is the case it means that `ObjectResult<>` is a value type.

Comment: Olivier Jacob-Descombes - I'm not sure what boxed means.  It's a generic object of the {System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectResult<POCOClass>} type.  If I cast it to {System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectResult<POCOClass>} then I can access ToArray/ToList etc... However, the POCOClass is piece is not known until runtime, so I can't explicitly cast it. I feel like I need to be able to cast the result using reflection.

Comment: I've been working on this for a long time, I'm ready to admit it's not possible.  From what I read, the value returned from .Invoke is a boxed object, and without knowing the type at compile time you cannot unbox it.

Comment: It's unclear what are you trying to achieve. From what I understand, you have `DbContext context`, `DbDataReader reader` and `Type type`, you need to call `Tranlsate` for that `type` and then what?

Comment: @IvanStoev I'm reading results from a SPROC.  I'm storing them in the current list object.  I would like them to be ObjectResults which get lazy-loading and other attributes (cache) of a DbSet.  Does that make sense?

Comment: @Brad I understand what your current code is doing (I have some posts regarding `Translate`, like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41744949/map-generic-child-to-generic-parent-from-stored-procedure-results/41751074#41751074) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39779270/dynamic-translate-to-avoid-c-sharp-syntax-errors/39798961#39798961)) What is still unclear is what do you want to do with `t`, which actually is a `ObjectResult<Something>` - create and return list etc. In other words, what is **that I want** in *The issue is that I can't do anything with 't' that I want*

Comment: @IvanStoev The problem is t is not ObjectResult<Something>, it's a boxed generic object of type ObjectResult<Something>.  As such, I can't do anything with it that I want...

Comment: @Brad I think I have a solution for you if you finally tell me **what do you want to do with it**.

Comment: @IvanStoev Back in my Controller, that receives current list object, I want to treat it like a ObjectResult, iterate over it, be able to do lazy-loading when accessing a navigational property, etc...  I can't do that when its boxed.

Answer (score 0):

Since `ObjectResult<T>` implements also the non-generic `IEnumerable` interface, cast it to this type and enumerate it.

```
var e = (IEnumerable)t;
foreach (object o in e) {
    //TODO: use o
}
```

Comment: I tried this.  I cannot run ToList() on e.  I get 'IEnumerable' does not contain a definition for 'ToList' ...  I have using System.Linq at the top already...  If I cast it like (IEnumerable<POCOClass>)t -- it works as expected and I can call ToList()...

Comment: If you ever have a chance to pass the currentType.Current as parameter, I suggest that you use [Generic Methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcad0zb.aspx) approach. In this situation, you will be able to use strong typed features, such as LINQ, ToList, etc. Otherwise, consider using the approach suggested by Olivier Jacot-Descombes, and populate the list of objects using the foreach loop.