# Map generic child to generic parent from stored procedure results

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I use a similar approach to the one described in [this](http://www.khalidabuhakmeh.com/entity-framework-6-multiple-result-sets-with-stored-procedures) post to map multiple stored procedure result sets to a parent and child entity using Entity Framework. However, every implementation of this approach that I've seen assigns the results of subsequent result sets (after the first) to properties of the parent entity directly; I'd like to accomplish this in a generic fashion.

So far I've been able to build a wrapper that successfully maps results in a one-to-many relationship. I don't need to care about enforcing the foreign key relationship in this case because the stored procedure handles that, but when selecting many parent entities, I need to somehow enforce the relationship.

How can I leverage the foreign key relationship in Entity Framework (using reflection, presumably) to enforce the mapping?

Here's what I have:

Entities

```
class FooEntity
{
     [Key]
     int Id { get; set;}

     ICollection<BarEntity> Bars { get; set; }
}

class BarEntity
{
     [Key]
     int Id { get; set;}

     int FooId { get; set; }

     [ForeignKey("FooId")]
     virtual FooEntity Foo { get; set; }
}
```

Generic stored procedure translator:

```
public class StoredProcedureTranslator<TDbContext> : IDisposable where TDbContext : DbContext, new()
{
    private DbCommand command;

    public StoredProcedureTranslator()
    {
        this.Context = new TDbContext();
    }

    public DbContext Context { get; set; }

    public DbDataReader Reader { get; set; }

    public StoredProcedureResult<T, TDbContext> Translate<T>(string procedureName, SqlParameter[] parameters) where T : class
    {
        this.command = this.Context.Database.Connection.CreateCommand();
        this.command.CommandText = procedureName;
        if (parameters != null)
        {
             this.command.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);
        }

        this.command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        this.Context.Database.Connection.Open();

        this.Reader = this.command.ExecuteReader();

        ObjectResult<T> results = ((IObjectContextAdapter)this.Context).ObjectContext.Translate<T>(this.Reader);
        return new StoredProcedureResult<T, TDbContext>(results.ToList(), this);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        this.Context.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Generic stored procedure result:

```
public class StoredProcedureResult<T, TDbContext> : IEnumerable<T>
    where T : class where TDbContext : DbContext, new()
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<T> results;

    private readonly StoredProcedureTranslator<TDbContext> translator;

    public StoredProcedureResult(IEnumerable<T> results, StoredProcedureTranslator<TDbContext> translator)
    {
        this.results = results;
        this.translator = translator;
    }

    public StoredProcedureResult<T, TDbContext> Include<TChild>(Expression<Func<T, IEnumerable<TChild>>> member) where TChild : class
    {
        T result = this.results.FirstOrDefault();

        if (result == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        if (!this.translator.Reader.NextResult())
        {
            return new StoredProcedureResult<T, TDbContext>(new List<T> { result }, this.translator);
        }

        // TODO: do some stuff with the fks
        ObjectResult<TChild> childResults = ((IObjectContextAdapter)this.translator.Context).ObjectContext.Translate<TChild>(this.translator.Reader);
        var prop = member.Body as MemberExpression;
        if (prop == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("blah blah");
        }

        var property = prop.Member as PropertyInfo;
        if (property == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("blah blah");
        }

        property.SetValue(result, childResults.ToList(), null);


        return new StoredProcedureResult<T, TDbContext>(new List<T> { result }, this.translator);
    }

    #region IEnumerable Impl

    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.results.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator<T> IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return (IEnumerator<T>)this.GetEnumerator();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Usage

```
using (var spt = new StoredProcedureTranslator<DbContext>())
{
     FooEntity foo = spt.Translate<FooEntity>("[dbo].[foo_get]", null).Include(f => f.Bars).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: What do you mean *enforce mapping*?  If you using EF to translate the entities to objects then attach the parent objects to the context under most circumstances EF with auto-wireup the parents/child objects to each other.

Comment: Even when using stored procedure result sets? I was under the impression that I would have to translate stored procedure result sets for each entity type individually (all `FooEntity`, then all `BarEntity`) and then assign all `FooEntity` members of type `ICollection<BarEntity>` myself, somehow respecting the FK relationship. Is there some magic method I'm missing?

Comment: I don't see you [attaching the parent objects to the context](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbset.attach(v=vs.113).aspx).

Comment: How will that help me? I cannot retrieve instances of the parent or child objects through the context except by calling this stored procedure. How will EF "know" to wire the parent and child objects when it cannot retrieve instances of the child objects?

Comment: [Lets talk about this in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133582/ap-generic-child-to-generic-parent-from-stored-procedure-results).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is intended to be used for **entity** types only, you can let EF context tracking infrastructure and relationship fix up do the work for you (pretty match like the EF materializes entity queries).

The trick is to use the following `Translate` method overload

```
public virtual ObjectResult<TEntity> Translate<TEntity>(DbDataReader reader, string entitySetName, MergeOption mergeOption)
```

and pass the `entitySetName` of the entity type.

Here is small helper utility class which does that (plus some other useful methods):

```
public static class EntityUtils
{
    public static string GetEntitySetName<T>(this IObjectContextAdapter dbContext) where T : class
    {
        return dbContext.ObjectContext.CreateObjectSet<T>().EntitySet.Name;
    }

    public static ObjectResult<T> ReadSingleResult<T>(this IObjectContextAdapter dbContext, DbDataReader dbReader)
        where T : class
    {
        return dbContext.ObjectContext.Translate<T>(dbReader, dbContext.GetEntitySetName<T>(), MergeOption.AppendOnly);
    }

    public static void Load<T>(this ObjectResult<T> source) where T : class
    {
        // Consume the enumerable by iterating it
        using (var en = source.GetEnumerator())
            while (en.MoveNext()) { }
    }
}
```

The `StoredProcedureTranslator` and `StoredProcedureResult` can be modified as follows (I find the design a bit flawed, but that's outside the scope of the question).

The result:

```
public class StoredProcedureResult<T> : IEnumerable<T>
    where T : class
{
    private readonly DbContext context;
    private readonly DbDataReader reader;
    private readonly IEnumerable<T> results;

    public StoredProcedureResult(DbContext context, DbDataReader reader)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.reader = reader;
        this.results = this.context.ReadSingleResult<T>(this.reader).ToList();
    }

    public StoredProcedureResult<T> Include<TChild>() where TChild : class
    {
        if (this.reader.NextResult())
            this.context.ReadSingleResult<TChild>(this.reader).Load();
        return this;
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.results.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Note that it doesn't need `TDbContext` generic parameter anymore, and all it does is to hold the root result set while providing fluent interface for reading the next results. The results are just translated and consumed, there is no need to be stored because during the consuming part EF will bind them to the already loaded related entities.

The translate method inside the `StoredProcedureTranslator` class:

```
public StoredProcedureResult<T> Translate<T>(string procedureName, SqlParameter[] parameters) where T : class
{
    this.command = this.Context.Database.Connection.CreateCommand();
    this.command.CommandText = procedureName;
    if (parameters != null)
        this.command.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);
    this.command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;   
    this.Context.Database.Connection.Open();    
    this.Reader = this.command.ExecuteReader();    
    return new StoredProcedureResult<T>(this.Context, this.Reader);
}
```

Usage:

```
using (var spt = new StoredProcedureTranslator<DbContext>())
{
     var foo = spt.Translate<FooEntity>("[dbo].[foo_get]", null)
         .Include<BarEntity>()
         .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: How does this work when the parent entity has more than one property of the same child entity type?

Comment: As soon as the SP returns all the related entities of the specific type (that's why my `Include` method does not need a property, but type), EF will tie them to the corresponding properties of the already loaded parent entities.

Comment: `public class ParentEntity{ public ChildEntity Child1 { get; set; } public ChildEntity Child2 { get; set; } }` this approach will not work for this parent entity.

Comment: Have to check that, but note that when you have single references like above `Child1` and `Child2` (instead of a collection), from db perspective what you call `ParentEntity` is actually a child (FK reference, dependent) of the `ChildEntity` (principal).